# read word to file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I want get from user word and put into place in file where is certian word.
I have problem with getline.
In new file I don't have any new line.
When I add Newline to string which I write to file, this line is read two times and writeto file to times (I think that bcoz I saw this newfile)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string contain_of_file,bufor,word,empty=" ",new_line="\n";
  string conection;
  string::size_type position;
   cout<<"Give a word";
 cin>>word;
 ifstream NewFile; 
 ofstream Nowy1;
 Nowy1.open("tekstpa.txt", ios::app);
 NewFile.open("plik1.txt");
 while(NewFile.good())
{
     getline(NewFile, contain_of_file);
    cout<<contain_of_file;

   position=contain_of_file.find("Zuzia"); 
    if(position!=string::npos)
    {
    conection=contain_of_file+empty+word+new_line;
  Nowy1<<conection;
    }
   Nowy1<<contain_of_file;

}
Nowy1.close();
NewFile.close();

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not your reading. directly, but about your *loop*.

Do not loop `while (stream.good())` or `while (!stream.eof())`. This is because the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. This means that the loop will iterate one extra time, and you try to read from the file but the `std::getline` call will fails but you don't notice it and just continue as if nothing happened.

Instead do

```
while (std::getline(NewFile, contain_of_file)) { ... }
```

---

And an unrelated tip: The variable `conection` is not needed, you can instead do just

```
Nowy1 << contain_of_file << ' ' << word << '\n';
```

Comment: When I change loop while, I have worse file. Now certain word disapear and it's not add word write by user. And it's not Newline too...

Comment: @user3164700 The loop condition should be correct, now you need to use a debugger to find out what other problems you have inside the loop.

Comment: So this statment in a loop do getline and add this to contain_of_file and if this loop see it's end of file just end work, I am right?

Comment: @user3164700 The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function returns the stream. And all stream objects can be used as [boolean expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).